# How do I interpret this disassembled code in IDA?

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly, decompiling, ida

I am working on a "figure out the password" type problem and believe I'd found the functions in question. What I am struggling with is understand what is happening in them.

```
int __cdecl __noreturn main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  __int64 v3; // rdx
  char *s; // [rsp+18h] [rbp-18h]

  if ( ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0LL, 1LL, 0LL) < 0 )
    exit(1);
  if ( argc != 2 )
    exit(2);
  s = (char *)argv[1];
  if ( strlen(s) != 8 )
    exit(3);
  if ( checkpw((__int64)s, 0LL, v3, (__int64)s) )
  {
    puts("Invalid Password!");
    exit(4);
  }
  puts("Correct Password!");
  exit(0);
}
```

I believe in the main command above, the password argument (2nd argument to the function - 1st command line argument) is being stored in "s". It's length is 8 thus checkpw is being run on its value.

What I'm not really following in this line:

```
  if ( checkpw((__int64)s, 0LL, v3, (__int64)s) )
```

Not sure what it is actually passing into checkpw (but I presume in the original program, it was s itself.

```
_BOOL8 __fastcall checkpw(__int64 a1, __int64 a2, __int64 a3, __int64 a4)
{
  unsigned __int8 v5; // cl
  char v6; // cl
  _BOOL8 result; // rax

  result = 1;
  if ( (*(_BYTE *)a4 ^ 0x52) == 17 && *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 7) == 35 )
  {
    v5 = *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 1);
    if ( (v5 ^ *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 2)) == 64 && v5 == 115 )
    {
      v6 = *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 3);
      if ( v6 > 35 && !__OFADD__(91, v6) && (*(_BYTE *)(a4 + 4) ^ 0xF3) == 0xC7 && (*(_WORD *)(a4 + 5) ^ 0x4C47) == 4660 )
        return 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Also trying to understand what exactly all this means in the context of the original string:

```
if ( (*(_BYTE *)a4 ^ 0x52) == 17 && *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 7) == 35 )
  {
    v5 = *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 1);
    if ( (v5 ^ *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 2)) == 64 && v5 == 115 )
    {
      v6 = *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 3);
      if ( v6 > 35 && !__OFADD__(91, v6) && (*(_BYTE *)(a4 + 4) ^ 0xF3) == 0xC7 && (*(_WORD *)(a4 + 5) ^ 0x4C47) == 4660 )
        return 0;
    }
```

Could someone please help (possibly with an example for the s value?

Comment: I don't see any disassembly in the question, only presumably the results of decompiling.  You left out the actual disassembly so people could see what the decompiler was looking at.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking at the decompiled output. Since there is no type information in assembly, the decompiler seems to think the memory addresses were just plain integers.

`char *s; // [rsp+18h] [rbp-18h]` shows that `s` is an address to where the string is stored. `if ( strlen(s) != 8 ) exit(3);` means the length of the string in `s` should be `8`, or otherwise the program will exit with an error code `3`.

`if ( checkpw((__int64)s, 0LL, v3, (__int64)s) )` here the *address* of `s` is passed to `checkpw`, not the value, and I don't know why it is passed twice.

Looking at the body of `checkpw`,

```
_BOOL8 __fastcall checkpw(__int64 a1, __int64 a2, __int64 a3, __int64 a4)
{
  unsigned __int8 v5; // cl
  char v6; // cl
  _BOOL8 result; // rax

  result = 1;
  if ( (*(_BYTE *)a4 ^ 0x52) == 17 && *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 7) == 35 )
  {
    v5 = *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 1);
    if ( (v5 ^ *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 2)) == 64 && v5 == 115 )
    {
      v6 = *(_BYTE *)(a4 + 3);
      if ( v6 > 35 && !__OFADD__(91, v6) && (*(_BYTE *)(a4 + 4) ^ 0xF3) == 0xC7 && (*(_WORD *)(a4 + 5) ^ 0x4C47) == 4660 )
        return 0;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

the first argument `a1` isn't even used, so you can just ignore the first `s` passed to `a1`.

I cannot do all of the decompiled bitwise logic for you in the body of `checkpw`, but if you grab a programmer's calculator and test with some possible inputs while looking at the hex and binary dump, you may find a hint.

Also, have a look at the ASCII table, it will help you a lot understanding what `checkpw` is doing. It seems it is doing a series of direct comparison with each character in the string to a certain ASCII value to check if the password is correct.